# Custom jQuery Hierarchy

Tags: jquery, tree, parent-child, hierarchy

I am using jQuery now to dynamically generate DIVs based off user input. With the nature of how these are generated and formatted, there's no direct parent/child relationship between the DIVs. In fact, I suppose the simplest way to explain it is the generation of a tree. I want to be able to create a custom hierarchy such that if an element at the top of the tree is deleted, so are all of it's pseudo-children.

A somewhat visiual example follows below. The Diagram follows a horizontal hierarchy.

```
Level 1   Level 2    Level 3
-----------------------------

   X        X          X  \
                       X   | >> These 3 elements are pseudo-children of 
                       X  /     the first elements in level 1 and level 2

            X   <<<<<< X  << The element in level 2 is pseudo-child of  
                       X     the first element in level 1

   X        X          X

            X          X
                       X
```

**UPDATE:**

Code Example:

```
<tr>
  <td>Level1</td>
  <td>Level2</td>
  <td>Level3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td />
  <td />
  <td>Level3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td />
  <td />
  <td>Level3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td />
  <td>Level2</td>
  <td>Level3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td />
  <td />
  <td>Level3</td>
</tr>
```

etc... (matching the diagram)

Comment: Are the level containers siblings?

Comment: Not really. It's table-formatted. So a level is a column, and a relationship is a row with specific TD's filled with content

Comment: So, when you delete an element at the top (an element from the first column), just delete the entire row (with all the pseudo-children). That wouldn't do it?

Comment: It would delete the parent if it shared the row, as well as only the first direct pseudo child.

Comment: Then you just need to keep deleting subsequent rows until you reach a row with an element of the same level... and also make sure that you *don't* delete the first row if it contains a parent element (but instead only clear the cells from the element to the right).

Comment: See edit for code example. It would still delete the parent

Comment: Yeah, it can be nit-picked, I was also debating giving each element custom attributes such as "parent_id" and "grandparent_id", but I was really hoping to do this a bit cleaner

Comment: So, let's say that we want to delete an element which is in the n-th column of its row. (1) Check if the previous cell in that row is populated. If no, delete the entire row. If yes, only clear the cells from the n-th cell to the right. (2) Jump to the next row and check if the first n cells are empty. If yes, delete that row and repeat step 2 with the next row. If no, you are done with the operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the [Flexible Box Module](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in HTML5.  See a really nice set of articles about it [here](http://www.the-haystack.com/2010/01/23/css3-flexbox-part-1/)

And the playground http://flexiejs.com/playground/ (along with a x-browser javascript library)

---

My guess is the only way to do this with a table in the UI is to also store a tree in memory and then use that to "know" what to delete.

---

Maybe I'm missing something but what is wrong with this:

```
<div id="a">
   <div id="b">
      <div id="c" />
      <div id="d" />
      <div id="e" />
   </div>
   <div id="f">
      <div id="g" />
      <div id="h" />
   </div>
</div>
<div id="i">
   <div id="j">
      <div id="k" />
   </div>
   <div id="l>
      <div id="m" />
   </div>
</div>



Level 1   Level 2    Level 3
-----------------------------

   a        b          c  \
                       d   | >> These 3 elements are pseudo-children of 
                       e  /     the first elements in level 1 and level 2

            f   <<<<<< g  << The element in level 2 is pseudo-child of  
                       h     the first element in level 1

   i        j          k

            l          m
                       n
```

Comment: The hierarchy is built using a drag and drop system. Unfortunately, this method becomes messy for user error.

Comment: +1 for the way I wish this could have worked out in the first place. After trying it for a bit, formatting and event listener interference became too much

Comment: Your answer would technically fulfill exactly what I need, there just isn't really the browser support for it yet. I believe I'll go with using custom attributes for the elements as described in my comment on the OP. Thanks, though, you've opened me up to a whole new world of flexibility!